# SWRevealViewController pan gesture recogniser issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using `SWRevealViewController` from John-Lluch. I need to use pan gesture to view the sidebars and I am using swipe to view my previous and next articles. However, the pan gesture can only be detected.

UPDATED: My swipe gesture worked if I disable my pan gesture.

**Pan Gesture**

```
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

**Swipe gesture**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *left = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)] autorelease];
left.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *right = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)] autorelease];
right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:left];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:right];
```

Comment: Add more code or detail to help interpret why you have used the swipe gesture recognizer...

Comment: i thing is not a problem in SWRevealViewController, check your swipe gesture

Comment: why you don't use it like: `-(IBAction) SwipeMe : (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer{
NSLog(@"swiped");
}` just link it to your view.

Comment: @Watsche My swipe gesture worked if I disable my pan gesture.

Comment: @NKB I already explained in my content. The pan is to open the sidebars where swipe to read articles.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik My swipe gesture worked if I disable my pan gesture.

Comment: @shoujo_sm Ya I got it man, where u add the swipe gesture method

Comment: I added it on self.view of view controller same the pan gesture.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:left];
```

Notice the difference? Implement the SwipeGesture as a property in your .h or make it in your .xib and link it to your .h

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to handle both pan and swipe gesture recognizer simultaneously. You will have handle the SWRevealViewController delegates for pan gesture and also swipe gesture for the current viewcontroller.

As apple suggests to differentiate the gesture you could use the following method

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Excerpt from the [Apple Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate)

> This method is called when recognition of a gesture by either
>   gestureRecognizer or otherGestureRecognizer would block the other
>   gesture recognizer from recognizing its gesture. Note that returning
>   YES is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition; returning NO, on
>   the other hand, is not guaranteed to prevent simultaneous recognition
>   because the other gesture recognizer's delegate may return YES.

Comment: Hi, I have already enable YES for the method but pan recogniser still overtook swipe movement

Comment: It will overtake but it should detect both the recognizers... There is no way you can priortise the gestures...